# PyGame seems to be intercepting SIGINT from Ctrl-C

Tags: python, pygame

If I attempt to black out the screen using PyGame, PyGame seems to intercept SIGINT and I cannot use control-C to exit my program. If I simplify my code to the most basic pieces, it looks like this:

```
import signal
import time
import pygame

class Foo:
     def __init__(self):
         self.bgcolor = [0,0,0]
         pygame.display.init()
         pygame.font.init()
         pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
         size = (pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h)
         self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
         self.blank_screen()

     def blank_screen(self):
         self.screen.fill(self.bgcolor)
         pygame.display.update()
         #pygame.quit()

     def sighandle(self, signal, frame):
         print('I got a ctrl-c')
         self.close()

     def close(self):
         print('calling close')
         pygame.quit()

     def run(self):
         print('I am running')
         time.sleep(10)

 if __name__=='__main__':
     bar = None
     try:
         bar = Foo()
         signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, bar.sighandle)
         signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, bar.sighandle)
         bar.run()

     finally:
         print('in finally block')
         if bar is not None:
             bar.close()
```

If I remove the pygame parts, ctrl-c works as expected, and `sighandle()`'s message is printed. When I put the pygame parts in, the screen blanks as expected, but ctrl-c is ignored, and `sighandle()`'s message is never printed. The code just runs to completion. Furthermore, if I uncomment the commented out `pygame.quit()` in `blank_screen()`, ctrl-c works again, but of course the blacked out screen goes away.

Why is the code ignoring ctrl-c when I invoke PyGame, and how do I make it work as I expect, so that ctrl-c kills the program through `sighandle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found that this is indeed the case by design. I don't see it explicitly mentioned in PyGame's documentation, though.

Ctrl-C can be enabled in the code above by handling it as an event. I can modify `Foo.run()` as such:

```
 def run(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.sighandle()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_c and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL:
            print "pressed CTRL-C as an event"
            self.sighandle()
     print('I am running')
     time.sleep(10)
```

I took the PyGame based screen blanking code from [Adafruit's VideoLooper](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-video-looper/overview), which also included the signal library based handling of SIGINT. But I don't think their code will handle Ctrl-C as-is either.